# Nesting stack navigation inside a drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I am trying to nest a stack navigation inside a drawer navigation on snack expo. I asked this question before and was told to do it all over again. I did and I still get different errors. I would really appreciated if someone could explain what am I doing wrong? I can also post the link to my project if this helps https://snack.expo.io/@andreeam/it-in-the-valley

Thank you

Errors below:

```
Device: (3:9741) (0,l.useLinkBuilder) is not a function. (In '(0,l.useLinkBuilder)()', '(0,l.useLinkBuilder)' is undefined)
```

And I also get

```
Device: (104:51757) r.render is not a function. (In 'r.render()', 'r.render' is undefined)

Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
  Evaluating module://react-native-screens.js
  Evaluating module://@react-navigation/drawer.js
  Evaluating module://App.js.js
  Loading module://App.js
```

Here is my app.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import ForgotPassword from './components/ForgotPassword';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Advertisers from './components/Advertisers';
import Adverts from './components/Adverts';
import Stats from './components/Stats';
import Plans from './components/Plans';
import ManageAdverts from './components/manageadvert';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class MyStack extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="SignIn"
      screenOptions={{
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#2d3436'},
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: { fontWeight: 'bold'}
      }}>

      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Reset your password" 
        component={ForgotPassword} 
        options={
          {title: 'Reset your password'},
          {headerLeft: null} 
        } 
        />

      <Stack.Screen 
        name="SignIn" 
        component={SignIn} 
        options = {
          {headerShown: false,
          title: 'SignOut'}
        }
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
       name="Dashboard" 
       component={Dashboard} 
      />

      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Advertisers" 
        component={Advertisers} 
        options={
          {title: 'Advertisers'}
        } 
      />

      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Adverts" 
        component={Adverts} 
        options={
          {title: 'Adverts'}
        } 
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Stats" 
        component={Stats} 
        options={
          {title: 'Stats'}
        } 
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Plans" 
        component={Plans} 
        options={
          {title: 'Plans'}
        } 
      />

      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Manage Adverts" 
        component={ManageAdverts} 
        options={
          {title: 'Manage Adverts'}
        } 
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}}


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack /> 
    </NavigationContainer>
);
}
}
```

Comment: You need to create a screen for your drawer then wrap your stack with it. If you need to open stack inside drawer, If you need to open drawer inside stack then you can create a non-header stack then create your drawer inside one of it's screens.

Comment: Looks like it might be complaining that you used a class, does it work if you turn MyStack into a functional component? `function MyStack() {
  return (`

Comment: Matt, I just tried that and I get Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
  Evaluating module://react-native-screens.js
  Evaluating module://@react-navigation/drawer.js
  Evaluating module://App.js.js
  Loading module://App.js

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I upgraded expo to version 37. I was able to resolve this issue by updating the relevant reactmodules to the latest version.